# Silverlight won't show proper height, or won't show list

Tags: windows, macos, silverlight, internet-explorer, debugging

I don't know what is happening with this `silverlight` application.

It works on `IE9` and bellow. But not on `IE10` (Not even on `compatibility mode`). Not on another browsers, and any browser that simulate the `Trident Engine` (`IE`'s) on `OS X`

I don't really have access to the application's Source code. The IE Debugger, and other browser's debuggers don't show a single thing about it.

I know nothing about silverlight. And they just dropped my this bomb on my job. Can someone point me, any differences between Silverlight on IE10 and IE9, differences between OSs? Anything will help. Really thank you!

It was supposed to show a list. But it won't show. Or will hide, because of the incorrect height.

[image: IE10 preview]

Comment: No differences between Silverlight IE10 and IE9. The problem is the HTML container height. Can you add a the HTML code of silverlight app host page ?

Comment: Does it work on any other browsers(Chrome, Firefox, etc.)?

Comment: No, it wont work on any other browser. Just in IE 9 and below

Comment: @Tonio I don't have access to the HTML/CSS/JS code...

Comment: On the Silverlight page press `CTRL+U`. The silverlight object, container, body and html  must have 100% height...

Comment: I managed to make it work on all of the Windows Browsers, by setting a height to it. It hasn't a height property. Setting it to 1000px did the job. But not on mac. This weird thing still happens.

Windows: http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/123/ygw.png
Mac: http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/2472/u1k.png

Same thing in all of the browsers on mac...

Comment: Try to set [overflow css](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property to show scrollbar...

Answer (score 1):

No difference, Silverlight must be run same on any Windows system (and without some features due to security problems at Mac).
I think, something not good with that app.
Maybe problem in HTML/JS/CSS? 
А.е. forced compatibility in script for all IE's?